# How to read data from a file in a python Gtk.ListStore?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I'm writing a python3/GTK programme that involves adding files containing genetics data to a Gtk.ListStore and then accessing that data using a ComboBox Entry. I've got as far as adding files to the list store but what I'm struggling with is how to select files and how to use that data. My relevant code for setting up the combo box is:

```
self.open_sequences = Gtk.ListStore(str)

class OsFrame(Gtk.Bin): #opens sequences for later use
  def __init__(self, open_sequences):

    Gtk.Bin.__init__(self)

    self.open_sequences = open_sequences

    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file("openseq-page.glade")
    self.os_box = self.builder.get_object("Open-box")
    self.add(self.os_box)

    self.combobox = self.builder.get_object("Open-cbox")
    self.comboentry = self.builder.get_object("Open-cbox-entry")
    self.filebox = self.builder.get_object("Open-file")
    self.filebox.connect("file_set", self.on_file_selected)        
    self.comboentry.connect("activate", self.enter_callback)

    renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    self.combobox.pack_start(renderer, True)
    self.combobox.add_attribute(renderer, "text", 0)
    self.combobox.set_model(open_sequences)

def on_file_selected(self, entry): #opens a file and adds it to list store
    file = open(self.filebox.get_filename())
    self.open_sequences.append([self.filebox.get_filename()])

def enter_callback(self, widget): #runs function when enter pressed
    self.open_sequences.append([self.comboentry.get_text()]) #adds typed text to liststore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem - adding filenames to the liststore and using a dictionary to store the data itself.